# SQL Server : Max is not working with a time var

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, max

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    SomeTable LV
WHERE 
    A IN ('0', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28')
    AND B <> 'ERRO'
    AND SAIDA <> 0 
    AND DATA IN (SELECT MAX(DATA) FROM SomeTable WHERE CB = LV.CB)
    AND HORA IN (SELECT MAX(Hora) FROM SomeTable WHERE CB = LV.CB 
                                                   AND DATA = LV.DATA)
    AND DATA >= CASE     
                   WHEN DATENAME(weekday, GetDate()) = 'Monday'  
                      THEN DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))   
                   ELSE DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))   
                END   
ORDER BY 
    DATA DESC, HORA DESC, B
```

Can anyone tell me why the `max(hora)` function is not working? It returns 0 values.

```
EXEC sp_help SomeTable

    Column_name Type    Computed    Length  Prec    Scale   Nullable    TrimTrailingBlanks  FixedLenNullInSource    Collation
    Data    date    no  3   10      0       no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
    Hora    time    no  3   8       0       no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

I want to select the maximum date and time.

For example, for a container, the date is the same in this case but it may not be like that for others.

```
NumLeitor   CB  Data    Hora    Saida   RepacDone   VerifDone   ReetiqDone

26  O7009419256 2017-07-17  23:02:57    1   0   0   0
25  O7009419256 2017-07-17  23:02:38    1   0   0   0
26  O7009419256 2017-07-17  22:52:14    1   0   0   0
25  O7009419256 2017-07-17  22:51:56    1   0   0   0
```

The `max(data)` works fine for cases with various dates, but the max(hora) - time - doesn't.

Comment: Great.  You've describe what *doesn't* work.  Now, write a question that includes sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you are trying to do, and a database tag so we can figure out what you do want to do.

Comment: I want to select the maximum date and time values.~

Comment: `MAX()` works fine with `TIME` datatype http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7185d/1

Comment: Yeah I though so. I don't understand why it's not working on this case. It shows as a TIME var

Comment: Your example is also working fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63cb3/1 There must be some other issue you are not showing us in sample code

Comment: Can you think of something else I could show to solve the problem? I did describe the table, everything looks ok..

Comment: What is the latest date, which fits conditions `A IN ('0', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28') AND B <> 'ERRO' AND SAIDA <> 0`?

Comment: It's constantly updating, this is from a distribution warehouse. Sometimes, containers stay in the operation zone I'm analysing more than one day and pass through the scanner more than once per day as they recirculate. That's why I want to select the most recent row.

Comment: Ok, but are you sure there exists records which date fits these conditions? It sounds stupid, but maybe there is a problem with data not `MAX`. Comment condition `AND DATA >= CASE     
                   WHEN DATENAME(weekday, GetDate()) = 'Monday'  
                      THEN DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))   
                   ELSE DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))   
                END` and check it if it returns any data.

Comment: Did that -- results in question.. something must be missing..

Comment: I am totally guessing now, because I can't look into your data, but, please, add conditions `A IN ('0', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28')
        AND B <> 'ERRO'
        AND SAIDA <> 0` to every `IN` clause (where you compare `DATA` and `HORA`), uncomment them and check if your query returns any data.

Comment: That solved it, I do not fully understand why, but thanks a lot. I though declaring the conditions at the "main" query would work.

Comment: Because `SELECT MAX(DATA) FROM SomeTable WHERE CB = LV.CB` will return maximum date for `CB` (from all records with specified `CB`, even if they do not fit conditions `A IN ('0', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28')
    AND B <> 'ERRO'
    AND SAIDA <> 0`), so it can happen that there is no record with that maximum date, where other conditions are satisfied. If you add these conditions to `MAX` query, you are looking maximum date among records which are satisfing all conditions. I hope, now it is clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your 'date' and 'time' fields and evaluate that.

```
select [MyDate]=CAST(DATA as DATETIME) + CAST(HORA as DATETIME)
```

Now use that to check against the 'max' datetime. Something like;

```
 SELECT 
    *
  FROM SomeTable LV
  WHERE A IN ('0','24','25','26','27','28')
  AND B <>'ERRO'AND SAIDA <>0
  and CAST(DATA as DATETIME) + CAST(HORA as DATETIME) in (SELECT MAX(CAST(DATA as DATETIME) + CAST(HORA as DATETIME)) FROM SomeTable WHERE CB=LV.CB)
  AND    DATA >=   
  CASE     WHEN DATENAME(weekday, GetDate())='Monday'  THEN  DATEADD(day, -3, convert(date, GETDATE()))   ELSE DATEADD(day, -2, convert(date, GETDATE()))   END   
  ORDER BY DATA DESC, HORA DESC,B
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 79
The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @JoãoSantos what version of SQL?

Comment: @JoãoSantos Change `CAST(HORA as TIME)` to `CAST(HORA as DATETIME)`.

Comment: It doesn't work even with the concatenation of date and time in a datetime var. Evaluating the max returns 0 values. Maybe it's a simple thing, but I have no idea what's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
        *
    FROM 
        SomeTable LV
    WHERE 
        A IN ('0', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28')
        AND B <> 'ERRO'
        AND SAIDA <> 0 
        AND DATA >= DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
    ORDER BY 
        DATA DESC, HORA DESC
) t
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, GetDate()) = 'Monday' 
    OR DATA >= DATEADD(day, -2, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))   
order by B
```